# Combining elements in strapi

Tags: strapi

I could use some help with strapi.
I would like to know if it is possible to make a structure like the one in the image.
Basically I should have a menu where I choose the opening hours and closing days of a restaurant and a bar.

I split the interface into two pieces in the content-type-builder:
-a single type called daysOff, in which I choose the days the restaurant/bar is closed.

-a collection type builder: in which I choose the days the restaurant/bar is open.

I would like to know if I can merge these contents into a single page (considering that the restaurant and the bar have the same structure).
In the attached images I also send my work on strapi.
Thank you very much in advance!

[image: Page example]

Closing days:
[image: Closing days]

Working days:
[image: working days]

Comment: You may implement it as a [custom field plugin](https://market.strapi.io/plugins?categories=Custom+fields) and data type could be json.